# Comparison of Strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-comparison

The following sets an NSString to the StringValue of a textfield. Then, the strings are compared in General_combinations

```
- (IBAction)SendAction:(id)sender
{
    NSString *MyLoggerCommand = [CommandBox stringValue];
    [CommandBox setStringValue:@""];
    [[[MyLogger textStorage] mutableString] appendString: MyLoggerCommand];
    [self General_Combinations];
}

- (void)General_Combinations
{
    NSLog(@"General Combinations called..");
    if([MyLoggerCommand isEqualToString:@"this"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Matched..");
    }
```

}

However, no matter what the strings are, they are never equal.
the snippet

```
[CommandBox setStringValue:@""];
```

shouldn't affect anything because the NSString is set first before the actual box is cleared.

Comment: It actually does, see my answer

Comment: This code doesn't make sense.  You declare a local variable in `SendAction:` and then reference that variable in the other method `General_Combinations` where it would not be available.  This code should crash at runtime... Is there a missing piece of code here that would make this work?

Comment: Yes, I declared the NSString at the top level. I was stupid enough to forget to pass the variable through the function.

Comment: Variables and methods should start with lower case letters and methods should not have "_" in the middle;  following coding patterns consistent with the system will make it easier to read/maintain your code (and make it less glaring to see on SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing MyLoggerCommand when the second method doesn't know what that is. Try this code:

```
-(IBAction)SendAction:(id)sender {

    NSString *myLoggerCommand = [CommandBox stringValue];
    [[[MyLogger textStorage] mutableString] appendString: myLoggerCommand];
    [self General_Combinations:myLoggerCommand];
    [CommandBox setStringValue:@""];  
}

-(void)General_Combinations:(NSString *)aString {

    NSLog(@"General Combinations called..");
    if([aString isEqualToString:@"this"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Matched..");
    }
 }
```

Comment: The strings still are not equal.

Comment: Ok, i just realized what the problem here is, I'll edit the answer

Comment: you can format source code with the {} button, does look a little better than a quote ;)

Comment: @Nick Weaver Thanks for the tip